# Find and replace numbers in textmate

Tags: regex, replace, textmate, oniguruma

I am trying to remove huge sequence of time stamp on a text file.

**It's formatted like this:**
Service Commands(04:59)
Using system-config-services(03:49)

**I want it to look like this:** 
Service Commands
Using system-config-services

I tried with the following wild cards ? and * to replace it by just leaving it empty:
**Find attempt1:**
`(??:??)`

**Find attempt2:**
`(\**:**)`

**Replace:**

Nothing happens. 
Am I using the correct wildcards for textmate? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Textmate supports regex.  In regex, `?` does not match a single character and `*` does not match multiple characters.  Assuming you selected the regex option in the TextMate find dialog, you can match what you're looking for with `\(\d\d\.\d\d\)`.  The parentheses and period need to be quoted with the backslash character because they are special characters.  \d will match a single digit.  See the regex documentation for more operations, such as how to specify how many digits in a row you want to match using `*`, `+` or `{}` notation.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was almost 100% correct as I assume that you meant `:` instead of `.` in `\(\d\d\:\d\d\)`. As your example was: `\(\d\d\.\d\d\)`. However, it works and I managed to remove all the time stamps and parentheses.

Comment: Actually, I meant `\.`, but only because my old eyes/brain didn't see/recognize both dots in the `:` you had all over the place. ;-) Glad it worked out.

Comment: Oh, and I'm pretty sure you don't need to escape the `:` in your regex.